# Python 2to3 warning <You should use 'operator.mul(None)' here.> What does it mean?

Tags: python, repeat, python-2to3

I am using 2to3 to convert a script. The only warning I get is:

```
RefactoringTool: Line 716: You should use 'operator.mul(None)' here.
```

Line 716 of the original script is:

```
classes = repeat(None)
```

I don't get where shall I use `operator.mul(None)`. The reference documentation of `repeat()` ([link to docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.repeat)) shows that I can pass `None` without any problem. So, what shall I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2to3 is just getting confused about which `repeat` you mean.  It thinks you're using `operator.repeat` in Python 2:

```
Help on built-in function repeat in module operator:

repeat(...)
    repeat(a, b) -- Return a * b, where a is a sequence, and b is an integer.
```

instead of `itertools.repeat`.  That's not a great guess on its part, to be honest, because `operator.repeat` takes 2 arguments, but that's what it's guessing.  You can see the transformation listed in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-operator).

You can avoid the warning by using the fully-qualified `itertools.repeat` or just ignore it.

Comment: Yes! indeed I am using itertools.repeat(). Now it's clear thank you!